# FirebaseUser How to get a User from Uid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to reach a user profile page. how can call a specific user with firebaseAuth. this code gives me only current user. how can call a user with user id.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

are there any code like this:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(mywantuserID);
```

why I want to use FirebaseAuth otherwise profile updates will take my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need an other user detail you need to store what you need at the firebase you can't use the auth method

Answer (score 1):

I believe the **FirebaseAuth** object only has the capability to get the currently signed-in user's details.

Maybe you could create a **User** object in your schema and have the **UID** from the **Firebase Users** as the key:

```
users
---UID
------first_name
------last_name
------etc...
```

And then with that, you get a user's ID with a simple Firebase Query like:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getReference('users').orderByKey().equalTo(yourUID)
```

Comment: I'm not very sure with the query, it's been a while since I've used Firebase but I hope you do get my point.

Answer (score -1):

To get user uid, simple use user.geUid();, for example:

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String userUid = user.getUid());
```

[Firebase documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)